# Why is apache refusing requests from 127.0.0.1?

Tags: apache, configuration

I am trying to restrict access to apache on one port (for example, 80) so that only the localhost can send requests (for example, for accessing APIs).

I have edited the /etc/apache2/ports.conf as

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:100
```

But when I call the API from localhost bash at one of the domains configured in apache, for example via

```
curl "https://www.example.com:100"
```

it returns

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.example.com port 100: Connection refused
```

Why is it refusing even if the call is from localhost?

Comment: Restart apache?

Comment: It was restarted

Comment: @pierpy and actually, if I ask to listen on the public ip of the server in ports.conf, then it becomes to open to all ips,

Comment: Virtual hosts conflict? Which distro are you using?